# Are there any disadvantages to look out for when using Optiboot?

Tags: arduino, software, firmware, bootloader

[Optiboot](https://code.google.com/p/optiboot/) appears to be superior to the official Arduino bootloader in just about every way. Despite this, is there anything I need to look out for when using this bootloader? Common pitfalls? Different behaviors? Is it a feature-for-feature replacement? Essentially, can I switch to this bootloader and forget about it?

Comment: Anecdotal evidence: I switched. No differences found so far,  on a half dozen different boards, mostly clones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official boards already ship with Optiboot (as do many clones).  The Uno was the first official board to start shipping with it.